# Javascript press button

Tags: javascript, button, click

Hey I'm working on a little script that will make something easier for me. What I have is an html form to submit something. What I want to happen is when I press the submit button, it travels to a different location and presses a button for me. How can I do this?

Comment: Thus far, all three answers use jQuery, which isn't much use to anyone (like me) who comes across this question looking for a way to do this using vanilla JS.

Comment: There's a pure JS answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17371962/798223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "different location" is another element on the same page, you should attach an event listener to the form's submit event. This listener will trigger a click on your "different location" target element.

```
<form id='myForm'>
...
</form>

<script>
$('form#myForm').bind('submit', function() {
    $('#otherElement').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Jquery != javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Javascript framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), then you can bind some javascript function to the "submit event", which occurs when your user submits the form. Inside that javascript function you can do whatever you want, including make changes to the current webpage and do 'click' events on other elements as well.

Your code might look something like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('some_other_html_elem').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to press a button in another page, you can use this in the destination page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual answer (Using JS, not Jquery):

So both buttons will do the same, but the second one actually presses the first one using JS.

```
<button id="hackerbtn" onclick="alert('I am a a hacker hahaha')">So this is your button</button>

<button onclick='document.getElementById("hackerbtn").click()'>Press above button using JS</button>
```