# Can javascript simulate a button click?

Tags: javascript, security, macros

I am designing a site where it would be problematic if macros were allowed to run freely.

I have thought of a way to stop a macro made by simulating the HTTP requests from a button click but this would be in vain if they could insert javascript scripts which just "click" the button and proceed as a normal user would.

By simulating a button click, I mean, the button is pressed and the Form the button is in runs with the php code associated with it.

Logic tells me javascript can do this but I would like to know for sure, thank you for any input!

Comment: What do you mean with macro, do you mean injecting javascript code in the forms? Or is [this](http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/javascript/javascript-injection-form-editing/) what you mean

Comment: Yes if someone added their own javascript to my site, which could simulate a button on my site being pressed. I would like to know if they can (are capable) of doing it.

Comment: They will always be able to insert javascript to do anything with your page, including sending http requests. There's no way you can avoid it.

Comment: You can add certain variables to the HTTP requests server-side which can make the correct http request hard/impossible to send.

But you are saying they can also easily click a button on my site using javascript?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to script a complete web browser, emulating every action a legitimate user could take. Indeed, exactly this is commonly done for browser testing and accessibility tools. So ultimately you can't stop automated requests. You can slow them down by using tools like rate-limiting and CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A button may be always clicked programmatically. For example you may have a page with a form like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Do something</button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then it is possible just to open debug console and type

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
```

which will click the button, or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].click();
```

which will click the submit button of the form, or just

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

to submit the form without clicking the button.

There is no way to prevent user from mastering JavaScript code on client. You have to add some validation on server side in order to prevent unwanted user actions.

Comment: I had to change `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].click();` to `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();`

Answer (score 3):

the only thing you can do is validate the request on the server.

once you hand the page over to a client, you have no technical control over how it might be used.

What you can do for example, [from](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?187045-Javascript-Address-Bar-Injection):

Say you're making javascript game. You use AJAX to send the score of the player to
the server for logging. After looking at the script, a malicious user could run your AJAX code
to send a score of 1,000,000 even if they earned only 5,000.

You can't prevent this from happening on the javascript side. However, there should some way to authenticate AJAX requests on the server side, you might be able to pass a security "token" to javascript that a hacker couldn't get ahold of.

Comment: I was thinking of having a server-side variable that changes every so often. The variable is the salt for the user's input, in the example of your score, they have 1000 score, using sha512 encryption, salt that number with a server-side variable, and then it knows what to expect. If the code is correct, update the score, else don't.

Obviously if this is all php side, they could just click the button to submit their score, not alter the score. However I want it to be impossible to even submit their score(in this case)

Comment: I guess I'm being a little too hopeful here, I'll have to settle with CAPTCHAS even though I wanted to avoid them at all costs :P I'll give ya the thumbs up for the effort though!

Comment: When I go about with mobile apps i sometimes utilize ssh libraries to encrypt and secure data transfers, maybe something similar can be done for your case...