# how to trigger a button click event using javascript in iccube-reporting

Tags: iccube-reporting

i am using iccube reporting.
i have a button of type Actions/Buttons placed on a dashboard, and a pivot table.
the button fires an iccube event upon click, the event refresh the pivot table.
how can i trigger a button click programmaticly, using java script ?

this is the html snippet (generated by iccube)

```html
<div class="ic3t-elegant ic3-fixed-layout-box ic3w-action ic3w-buttonlist  **buttonRefreshCls** ic3h-no-header ic3-box-unselectable" id="ic3-9" style="top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 130px; height: 30px; z-index: 4;"><div class="ic3-loading-div-back"></div><div class="ic3-loading-div"></div><span class="ic3-stop-loading fa fa-stop" title="Stop Loading"></span>  <div class="ic3-fixed-layout-menu-container">    <div class="ic3-fixed-layout-edit ic3-jui-app"></div>      </div>  <div class="ic3-inner">    <div class="ic3-box-header">       <div class="ic3-box-nav-menu" style="display: none;"></div>       <div class="ic3-inner" style=""></div>    </div>    <div class="ic3-box-content" style="width: 130px; height: 30px;">      <div class="ic3-inner" style=""><div id="ic3-17" class="ic3-widget"><div class="ic3-action-list ic3-item-container ic3-item-horizontal ic3-bt-blue"><div class="ic3-item" style="" ic3-idx="0" title="">Manual Refresh</div><div style="clear:both"></div></div></div><div class="ic3-widget-data"></div></div>    </div>  </div>  <div class="ic3-chart-filter-info">  </div></div>
```

as you can see there's no input button that you can trigger with js.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('buttonRefreshCls')[0].click();
```

thanks in advance, assaf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can javascript simulate a button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371569/can-javascript-simulate-a-button-click)

Comment: You've the id so better use getElementById