# Make a button click itself

Tags: javascript, button, console

I just want to make so I can paste the script into the f12 dev console and the button with specific id is going to click itself 10 times.

Comment: select the button, click it using `click()` inside a for loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371569/can-javascript-simulate-a-button-click

Comment: The second one works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using plain JavaScript like this:

- You can use setTimeout() to give you time to paste your snippet into the console.
- Afterwards you can use setInterval() to execute the button click on a specified interval.(You need to clear the interval to stop it from executing)
- You use document.getElementById("button-id").click() to click your button.

Lets combine all of this in a snippet:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
         document.getElementById("button-id").click(); // Clicks the button
         counter++; // Increases counter after every click
         if(counter == 10) clearInterval(interval); // Stops after 10 clicks
    },1000); // Will click the button every second
}, 10000) // Starts after 10 seconds
```

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function reClick(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
       $("#button-id").click(function(){
          alert("Clicked");
       });
    }
```

}
$("#button-id).click(reClick());

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please add some explanation, like how this code works and how it fixed the problem?